# Show attendees on a page

Tags: gui-design

I want to design a page where i need to show people who are currently logged in and are on that page similar to a chat room where everyone can see each other. I want to give that page a feel so that the attendees give a realistic type of feeling. :-) How can i show attendees my page? Any Suggestions/pointers will be of great help. If possible please share a link if you have anything in your mind which is currently live on internet.

Comment: Welcome to QX.SE Hitesh. It might make sense for you to try giving this a go yourself and if you run into difficulties on a particular part, to ask a question on specifically that. Afterall, we're not a free UX design service. ;)

Comment: @nightning Lolz... I get that. I am definitely going to give it a shot myself. I was thinking if i get better ideas on the forum. I am not at all good in UI. So was expecting some  advice from great minds out there. Anyways! Thanks.

Comment: Some general tips: Put yourself in the shoe of your attendees and ask what would you like to see as an attendee? Maybe look for other attendees you personally know? Or better yet, ask the question why would you want to interact with other attendees and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your website/app wants to go a little onto the social networking side, but not completely.

You want to show the presence of users on the website, but do not want to dwell completely into a messenger type model.

I completely believe the idea is great since it interests the user in knowing what other people might be doing.

Let's assume your website is a good place for people to talk about **X**.

Depending on the User-Interface you're following on the website, you could fetch the activity the person is performing online and showcase it to say a Live Feed (provided the activity isn't sensitive).

The best example I could possibly give you is **Spotify's Windows App**.

[image: Social Features on Spotify]

They recently added a social feature onto their app, which shows you in Real time on what people you followed might be listening to.

*-Sorry, my friends weren't in the mood to listen to music when I took the screenshot :(*

It's a great way to discover new music.

Similarly, on your website, users could discover what other online users might be finding, speaking, discussing about X.

It shouldn't be too attractive, but should only convey: Hey, if you're bored, here's what others who are online are doing.

Only showing the Usernames online on your website does not really contribute to anything and is only confusing or forced. However if you could get your website content to flow through social features, you'd do a much better social integration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in your question. You could incorporate patterns similar to a chat room in your design. Could be as a side bar with a list or a grid, similar to facebook. showing green indicators that they are online http://www.onlinesocialmedia.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Facebook-Chat-Body-11.jpg